# Convert serialize() to array of objects to post to controller

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization, datatables

I am using Datatables. I have a table with multiple inputs and I want to post array of objects to controller via ajax.

```
var data = table.$('input, select').serialize();
```

The result:

```
row-1-location=123&row-1-lot=231545&row-2-location=2323&row-2-lot=5523&row-3-location=23232&row-3-lot=23235
```

I am assuming I need to split the string at every second '&', then split again.
The question is, is this the only way to convert it to array of objects?

The result I want is array of objects:

```
[{location : 123, lot: 231545}, {location: 2323, lot: 5523}......]
```

**HTML:**

```
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td><input type="text" id="row-5-location" name="row-5-location" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="row-5-lot" name="row-5-lot" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
        <td><input type="text" id="row-6-location" name="row-5-location" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="row-6-lot" name="row-5-lot" value=""></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks!

Comment: In this: _post array of objects to controller._ do you mean POST as in "to controller on server via HTTP"? If so, then `data` simply becomes the BODY of your POST request.

Comment: I want to post to function in mvc via ajax

Comment: It would make more sense to just build the array of objects directly from the DOM elements. If you can show us what the HTML looks like I'm sure we can give you an example of how to do that

Comment: Updated with html code.

Comment: Thanks, I added an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the array of objects you require it would make more sense to just build the structure from the DOM directly instead of serialising it, then picking apart the resulting string.

To achieve this you can select the parent `tr` elements then use `map()` to build the objects. The only HTML change which would make it simpler still would be to put common classes on the `input` elements. Something like this:

```js
var arr = $('table tr').map(function() {
  var $tr = $(this);
  return {
    location: $tr.find('.location').val(),
    lot: $tr.find('.lot').val()
  }
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td><input type="text" class="location" id="row-5-location" name="row-5-location" value="123"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="lot" id="row-5-lot" name="row-5-lot" value="231545"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td><input type="text" class="location" id="row-6-location" name="row-5-location" value="2323"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="lot" id="row-6-lot" name="row-5-lot" value="5523"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is one drawback in this approach. We can only get data from rows that presented in DOM. But if I use searchbox then I will not be able to get previously entered data.

Comment: Potentially, but using `serialize()` has the same drawback as that is only populated from the DOM too.